# Problems with subsetting in R using a specific value

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and ran into a weird issue. I'm trying to subset a data frame, however it fails if the value used for sub-setting is entered in a specific way.

For example, this is the original data frame:

```
      X time_mean temp_mean covas_mean
1  1426     28.50     45.02         77
2  1427     28.52     45.18         77
3  1428     28.54     45.06         77
4  1429     28.56     45.01         77
5  1430     28.58     45.01         77
6  1431     28.60     45.04         77
7  1432     28.62     44.97         77
8  1433     28.64     45.02         77
9  1434     28.66     44.91         77
10 1435     28.68     44.99         76
11 1436     28.70     44.77         76
```

If I try to subset using this code, it fails creating an empty data frame:

```
# This does not work
var <- 23 + 0.7 + 0.9
subset(data, time_mean == var+4.00)
[1] X          time_mean  temp_mean  covas_mean
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

If I subset like this, it works:

```
# This works
var <- 23 + 0.7 + 0.7 + 0.1 + 0.1
subset(data, time_mean == var+4.00)
     X time_mean temp_mean covas_mean
6 1431      28.6     45.04         77
```

Any ideas what is going on? Thank you.

R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
macOS 10.13.4 (17E202) (x86_64, darwin15.6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a  floating point issue. You can use `round` and use 2 digits and `subset` will work.

```
> subset(df, time_mean == round(var+4.00, 2))
     X time_mean temp_mean covas_mean
6 1431      28.6     45.04         77
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Still puzzling that apparently equivalent mathematical operations can render different results in R

Answer (score 0):

FAQ 7.31
Or what every computer scientist should know about floating-point numbers

Comment: Could you provide a link?